# How can I monitor Wifi status for Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, wifi

I want to write an application for monitoring the status of WIFI, for example, if Linux connects to an AP, I can get a notification for telling me the Wifi has been ready. For the system, the "iw" and "wpa_cli" commands are available. So what should  I do? Create a new thread for scanning the wifi every 5 seconds? Does anyone have better solution for that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

We are currently experiencing a radical change in that part of the Linux system. You might have heard about the `systemd` debate? `systemd` will replace good old SysV Init. In this process of changes also the way to monitor network interfaces will change. While today's distros' solutions are based on scripts triggered by `init` (or `upstart` (on Ubuntu)), upcoming distros will be based on `systemd` scripts. I've not worked with `systemd` so far, but I found this documentation on the networking monitoring topic: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/ . All distributions agreed that they will integrate `systemd` as fast as possible, so a future proof solution should use it.

---

Before `systemd` (until today):

On Debian/Ubuntu you can add a script to the folder `/etc/network/if-up.d`. Executables in that folder will be called every time an interface gets "up". Analogue to that you can also use the folders `if-down.d`, `if-post-down.d`, `if-pre-up.d`. Parameters like the interface id and some others will get passed to the script. On Debian/Ubuntu check [`man interfaces`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/interfaces.5.html) for more information.

Other distros might have their own mechanisms for that.

Comment: Thank hek2mgl. But how can use it in my c/c++ application?